# How to generate random names when given two arrays of objects with key value pairs

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to solve an algorithmic problem from codewars.

Given a function `aliasGen(){}` with an object `{ '0': 'Mike', '1': 'Millington' }` as an argument, I need to extract the first letter of each value and  match them to other data objects `firstName = [{ A: 'Alpha', ...etc] && surname=[{ A: 'Analogue', B: 'Bomb',C: 'Catalyst', ...etc}]` to  generate a random alias.

`firstname` and `surname` are given and contain the "random names" to match from

```js
var firstName = { A: 'Alpha', B: 'Beta', C: 'Cache', D: 'Data', E: 'Energy', ...etc}
var surname = { A: 'Analogue', B: 'Bomb', C: 'Catalyst', D: 'Discharge', E: 'Electron', ...etc}
```

Some of the test cases

```js
Test.assertEquals(aliasGen("Mike", "Millington"), "Malware Mike");
Test.assertEquals(aliasGen("Fahima", "Tash"), "Function T-Rex");
Test.assertEquals(aliasGen("Daisy", "Petrovic"), "Data Payload");
```

**Special Cases**

1. If the first character of either of the names given to the function is not a letter from A - Z, you should return "Your name must start with a letter from A - Z."
2. Sometimes people might forget to capitalize the first letter of their name so your function should accommodate for these grammatical errors.

This is the kata just in case: [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/578c1e2edaa01a9a02000b7f/train/javascript)

I actually think I'm over engineering this.  Right now I'm actually stuck on the **Special Cases**.

This is  what I have now.

```js
function aliasGen(){
    // Code Here
  // console.log(firstName)
  // console.log(surname)
  
  console.log(arguments) // { '0': 'Mike', '1': 'Millington' }

  let  propertyNames  = Object.values(arguments)
  console.log(propertyNames) // [ 'Mike', 'Millington' ]

  var firstLetters = propertyNames.map(name => name[0])
  
  console.log(firstLetters, 'firstLetters') [ 'M', 'M' ] 'firstLetters'
  
  let lettersRegexp = /[A-Z]/;
  
  if (firstLetters.map( letter => lettersRegexp.test(letter))) {
    
    var firstNamePseudoObj = Object.keys(firstName)
    .filter((key) => key.includes(firstLetters[0]))
    .reduce((obj, key) => {
        return Object.assign(obj, {
          [key]: firstName[key]
        });
  }, {});
  
  var lastNamePseudoObj = Object.keys(surname)
    .filter((key) => key.includes(firstLetters[1]))
    .reduce((obj, key) => {
        return Object.assign(obj, {
          [key]: surname[key]
        });
  }, {});
  
  let arrayOfPseudos = [Object.values(firstNamePseudoObj), Object.values(lastNamePseudoObj)].map(arr => String(arr)).join(' ')
  
  console.log(Object.values(firstNamePseudoObj), 'firstPseudo') // [ 'Malware' ] 'firstPseudo'

  console.log(Object.values(lastNamePseudoObj), 'lastPseudo') [ 'Mike' ] 'lastPseudo'

  
  console.log(arrayOfPseudos) Malware Mike

  
  return arrayOfPseudos
     
  }  else {
        return `Your name must start with a letter from A - Z.`
  }
}
```

I fail the following test cases

```js
Log
{ '0': 'Anuddanumbha', '1': '23200' }
[ 'Anuddanumbha', '23200' ]
[ 'A', '2' ] 'firstLetters'
false
[ 'Alpha' ] 'firstPseudo'
[] 'lastPseudo'
Alpha 

Expected: 'Your name must start with a letter from A - Z.', instead got: 'Alpha '

---

Log
{ '0': '82ckt', '1': 'vuvmy' }
[ '82ckt', 'vuvmy' ]
[ '8', 'v' ] 'firstLetters'
false
[] 'firstPseudo'
[] 'lastPseudo'


---

Log
{ '0': 'di5io', '1': 'tudou' }
[ 'di5io', 'tudou' ]
[ 'd', 't' ] 'firstLetters'
false
[] 'firstPseudo'
[] 'lastPseudo'
 
Expected: 'Data T-Rex', instead got:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply take the first character of values passed to you, and then you need to check if it is an alphabet or not.

```
function aliasGen(first, second) {
  let firstNameChar = first[0].toUpperCase()
  let lastNameChar = second[0].toUpperCase()

  if (/[A-Z]/.test(lastNameChar)) {
    return firstName[firstNameChar] + " " + surname[lastNameChar]
  } else {
    return "Your name must start with a letter from A - Z."
  }
}
```

Comment: Zuuuuttttt that's so much much simpler . Thanks @Code Maniac

Comment: slightly cleaner than `/[a-z]/i` is `/[A-Z]/` We already know we're in upper case.

Comment: @ScottSauyet but question say `Sometimes people might forget to capitalize the first letter of their name so your function should accommodate for these grammatical errors.` https://www.codewars.com/kata/578c1e2edaa01a9a02000b7f/train/javascript

Comment: ... but you already call `toUpperCase()`.  Alternately, you could keep the insensitive test and remove the `toUpperCase()`.  But having both is a bit redundant.